# May I use imported DLL function inside my application's atexit handler?

Tags: c++, dll, atexit

I have a c++ program which loads a DLL at startup by using:
 `#pragma comment(lib, "my.lib")` . I also register atexit function at the beginning of my main function `std::atexit(atexit_handler);`. In my atexit handler function I call a function imported from DLL. Is that safe, or rather is there a guarantee that my DLL will still be loaded when I need it inside atexit function?

Comment: That #pragma doesn't load anything, it merely tells the linker that it needs to link the DLL's import library.  Which ensures the DLL gets loaded when your program starts up and doesn't unload until it terminates.  So yes, no problems.

Comment: Some consider use of `atexit` a code smell. It would probably be a better idea to perform any final actions prior to returning from `main`.